# Error when setting compileSdkVersion to Sv2 (Android 12L) - Unsupported value: Sv2. Format must be one of

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, apple-m1, android-12

I am trying to follow the setup guide for Android 12L [here](https://developer.android.com/about/versions/12/12L/setup-sdk). But I get the following error when I sync gradle on the project:

```
Unsupported value: Sv2. Format must be one of:
- android-31
- android-31-ext2
- android-T
- vendorName:addonName:31
```

I am using `gradle-7.3-rc-1` and I already have `Android Sv2 Preview` SDK downloaded. I tried building with this config on both my main project and a fresh new project with the same result. I am on an M1 Mac (if that makes any difference).

Answer (score 1):

I have a final working code like this.

```
compileSdkVersion "android-Tiramisu"
```

And

```
targetSdkVersion "Tiramisu"
```